# git same project, two separate repos - how to merge together

Tags: git, git-merge

Two repos of the same project with different histories (unrelated from the git point of view).  I need to merge them into one repo and remember histories of both.

The main problem is that the one of the repos one additional directory.

```
 repo1  ---DIR----[project dirs]


 repo2  ---[project dirs]
```

The project dirs are almost the same.

I have tried to move the directories, create dummy branches, then merge unrelated histories and then merge. But it never see the conflicts - it just replaces files using one of the repos.

Is it possible to merge two separate repos?

Comment: Just add `repo2` as a remote to `repo1`, try to pull from the newly added remote it and resolve the possible conflicts(Don't forget to commit after resolving the conflicts)? After that, you can push to the common repository.

Comment: @dan1st but then I have `DIR` and `[project dirs]` at the same level and another `[project dirs]` in the DIR directory. I want to merge `[project dirs]`

Comment: Try [`git subtree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992078/7976758). Backup `repo1` and run in it `git subtree add --prefix=DIR repo2 master`

Comment: @phd `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: PS and there is no  `--allow-unrelated-histories`